# JSON object with empty fields

Tags: java, android, json, foursquare

I'm getting a list of venues from foursquare and I need the name, the address and the city of each venue that I get. Here my problem is if address or city is empty, it gives an error and says " JSON Exception: No value for address". I tried different ways to fix it but couldn't solve the problem. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

```
JSONObject b = venues.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject location = b.getJSONObject("location");

String name = "";
String address = "";
String city = "";

if ("".equals(b.get("name"))) {
    //  Toast.makeText(Activity2.this,"Name of Place: " +name+ " Location: "+country, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    name = "No place ";
} else {
    name = b.getString("name");
}

if ("".equals(location.getString("address"))) {
    address = "No address";
} else {
    address = location.getString("address");
}

if ("".equals(location.getString("city"))) {
    city = "No city";
} else {
    city = location.getString("city");
}

name = "Name of the place: " + name; 
// + " Address: "+ address + "  City: " + city;
list.add(name);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely need to call the has() method prior to calling getString to avoid the exception. But there's an even simpler way - just use the [optString](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead of getString, which will return the "fallback" string if the value does not exist.

```
String name = location.optString("name", "No Place");
String address = location.optString("address", "No Address");
String city = location.optString("city", "No City");
```

Comment: thanks mate it is nice to know this optString function

Answer (score 3):

The .Json object "`location`" doesn´t contain `address` value, you have to add another evaluation.

```
location.getString("address") = null;
```

for example:

```
if ((location.getString("address") = null) || "".equals(location.getString("address"))) {
    address = "No address";
} else {
    address = location.getString("address");
}
```

or see selbie´s solution using `optString()` method

```
String address = location.optString("address", ""); //where "" is a default value.
```